# Bad design letting controller return an Object?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

Hi is this bad design? I would like return Profile if everything goes according to plan. If not I would like to return my custom error message.

Is this ok?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody
Object saveUser(@PathVariable Long userId, ModelMap data, @Valid Profile profile, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return ValidationUtil.createValidationErrors(bindingResult);
    }
    profileService.save(profile);
    return profile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use  **@ExceptionHandler (Exception.class) and @ResponseStatus Annotation**

Example

```
@ExceptionHandler (Exception.class) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT) 
public @ResponseBody 
Profile saveUser(@PathVariable Long userId, ModelMap data, @Valid Profile profile, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse response) { 

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) { 
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); 
        throw new Exception("message");
        if(ValidationUtil.createValidationErrors(bindingResult)) {
            throw new Exception("message");
        }
    } 
    profileService.save(profile); 
    return profile;
}
```

For more details refer

http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbNov2010.html

http://www.stormpath.com/blog/spring-mvc-rest-exception-handling-best-practices-part-1

http://blog.cuttleworks.com/2011/12/spring-restful-controllers-and-error-handling/

Comment: I am not implementing the fron end. Can the person accessing my API still use the model?

Comment: Does, it is a RESTFUL web service ? or some other service API ?

Comment: The bindingresult does not through an excpetion on validation errors. the controller methos should not be annotated with @ExceptionHandler (Exception.class) ?

Comment: if there are any binding error or validation error then your code should throw customized user defined exception. above code is just a sample with generic Exception

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the profile object, I'd suggest you add it to the session or the request context. Then you can return a string from your saveUser method (or a ModelAndView object, if you prefer), and still have the object available to later requests.

Comment: I just need to return a json object. I dont need the Profile.

Comment: Again, you can place the JSON object into the request (or Model) or into the session, and then return a string.

Comment: I am just implementing an API. The model is just available if I create the front end with jsps?

Comment: No, a model is returned to the browser with the objects named in the request. The easiest thing (I think) for you to do is to create a ModelAndView object. Then set the view in that object, and add the JSON object into it also. Returning that will send the browser to the correct link and place the JSON object in the response scope for the browser to access